# VS 2019 SSRS Data Source Build Button Disabled for Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, visual-studio-2019

I have installed VS19
I have also installed extension for ssrs
I am able to connect to my sql server but not oracle
ODT is already present. 
I was able to design reports using VS13

[image]

Comment: Not entirely sure why it is disabled. I checked and it is disabled for me as well. Why not just write the connection string? Go here -> https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: Hi, same issue for me as well, any idea how to resolve this error

Comment: Hi , Issue is resolved. It seems that you need to enable correct ODAC libraries to be specific 32 bit , 64 bit add GAC entries, machine configs then the build button will be enabled. follow - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/oracle-connection-type-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15